# how to apply animation in load function?

Tags: jquery, html

I have a ul list of items and I am loading the newly added item with jquery load() function and I want to load the item with some animation

```
$('#ulitems').load(location.href + ' #ulitems').fadeIn(1000);
```

I have used fadeIn(1000) or fadeIn('1000') like this but its not working

html code generated in browser after adding new item

```
<ul class="list-group list-group-flush" id="ulitems">
 <ul class="list-group list-group-flush" id="ulitems">
   <li class="list-group-item items">asd</li>
   <li class="list-group-item items">Market</li>
   <li class="list-group-item items">Gym</li>
   <li class="list-group-item items">tea</li>
   <li class="list-group-item items">b</li>
 </ul>
</ul>
```

jquery code

```
$('#btnAddItem').click(function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var text = $('input').val();
  $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'list',
      data: {
          'text': text
      },
      success: function (data) {
          //alert(data.success);
          console.log(data);
          $('#ulitems').load(location.href + ' #ulitems').fadeIn(1000);
      }
  });
```

I want to add some animation in newly added li element. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. `.load()` is async
2. You wish to add all inner elements of ul instead of wrapping it in itself, so add `#ulitems > *`.
3. When adding new elements they are already visible, so first hide it:

---

```
$('#ulitems').load(location.href + ' #ulitems > *', function () {
    $('#ulitems').hide().fadeIn(1000);
});
```